# Congruency Modulo - How to Derive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm wondering how to derive $41 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$ or $2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$. Is there a formula for that?

Comment: You just do integer division $41 : 7$ with remainder, so $41=7\cdot 5+6$, so the remainder is $6$.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition, $a\equiv b \pmod c$ iff $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $c$.

$41$ has a remainder of $6$ when divided by $7$.

$2$ has a remainder of $2$ when divided by $7$.